# Does Adobe Brackets support PHP now?

Tags: adobe, adobe-brackets

I was wondering if PHP is now supported in Adobe brackets as I can't find a definitive answer anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of support are you looking for? Like many other code editors, Brackets has syntax highlighting for PHP built-in, but you'll need to download an extension for additional functionality like code hints. There are a bunch of popular PHP extensions available: just go to *File > Extension Manager* and search for "PHP."